# how to repeat each row twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement for a report and I would like my sql query to repeat each row twice.

Example :

```
  **Table 1**
   Id   Name
   1     Ab
   2     Cd
   3     Ef
```

I want to write a query which outputs the following :

```
  1   Ab
  1   Ab
  2   Cd
  2   Cd
  3   Ef
  3   Ef
```

Is there a way I can do it ?

I cannot think of anything except using `union`

```
Select Id, name from Table1 union select Id, name from Table1
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a `union all`.  A `union` will not work, because it will eliminate duplicates. Another way is a `cross join`:

```
select id, name
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

Comment: +1 for cross join. With any sort of a union solution, you'll have to maintain any changes to your query twice.

Comment: Or a marginally more concise version `select id, name from table1 CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2)) V(n)`

Comment: Could you be very kind to clarify what the following row `(select 1 as n union all select 2) n` means? Especially, `select 1 and select 2`.

Comment: @StepUp . . . That creates a derived table with two rows and one column.  In one row, the value of the column is "1".  In the other, it is "2".

Comment: @GordonLinoff But the OUTPUT should be `1  Ab 1
1  Ab 2
2  Cd 1
2  Cd 2
3  Ef 1
3  Ef 2`. How `UNION ALL` makes the seconds row to be the same like the previous row. I just pull my head. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StepUp . . . You can use `order by` if you need the results in a particular order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, no, I mean why is there no `1` and `2` values? However, there is a sequential repeatable rows.

Comment: @stepUp . . . Because the OP did not request an output like that.  You can include `n.n` in the `select`, if that's what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do not want that, I would like to know just how it works. If it is possible, could you clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `UNION ALL`, put them under `CTE` (Common Table Expression) and `Order By Id`:

```
WITH CTE AS
( 
SELECT Id, Name FROM Table_1
    UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Name FROM Table_1
)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Id;
```

As this will **reorder** them and **stacked them** as duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Solution will be like this:

```
select Id, name from Table1 
union all 
select Id, name from Table1
```